# Spring REST design public and authenticated API

Tags: spring, rest

I'm trying to design an application that should expose two global API path:

- `/` user must be authenticated
- `/public` no authentication

Moreover `/public` API will offer light version of some `/` API by displaying less informations that is not authorize if no authentication is provided.

Even if `Controller` does not contains core function, some of them provide data validation or other check. Thus if I want to create a `/public` version of a current API I have 4 solutions:

1. Duplicate code
2. `@Autowired` `/` controller and use method call
3. `forward` request (I can't `redirect` because security filter will be applied)
4. Create `Controller` that manage both `/` and `/public` API

Is there any good practice or pattern for my scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, Best way to solve this problem is by using 4th solution.
1st solution: First rule of computer science is you do not duplicate your code.

2nd solution: calling controller from another controller is a serious design flaw.

3rd solution: could have been a solution but ruled out by you.

4th solution: IMHO best one in your case

```
class MyController{

    @RequestMapping("/getData")
    public ResponseObject getData(@RequestBody SomeDTO dto){
      Validator.validate(dto);
      return myService.getData(dto);
}

    @RequestMapping("/public/getData")
    public ResponseObject getPublicData(@RequestBody SomeDTO dto){
      Validator.validate(dto);
      return myService.getPublicData(dto);
}
}
```

Filter data in your service layer.

Comment: I think is proper way to do! I should create external `Validator` as you suggest indirectly to allow *share-ability*

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to be achieved with Spring Security.
First, you will need to enable this URL to be called without security, like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /** some security code **/
        http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**","/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        /** other stuffs **/

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/public")
public class PublicRestController {

    @Autowired private DataRepository data;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Model getModelData(){
    /** Do what you need here **/
    }
}
```

So, all you have to do is build a REST Controller to match your URL and you are done.

And as you suggested, use @Autowired to expose only the code that you need. So you can put all your login on service/component beans and serve them as needed.